# Systemd Automount Failing on Program Execution

Tags: systemd, automounting, systemd-unit, systemd-mount

I set up a systemd automount for an external drive by UUID. I basically just wanted the drive to mount whenever it's accessed. It was working fine but I noticed some issues when loading Evince first, then Inkscape. Both programs would just hang and I had to `kill -9` to get them closed. After digging around, I found that both were somehow activating the mountpoint of the automount, without the drive even being plugged in. This caused the hang. Here is some output:

```
[chris@archpc ~]$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/mnt-external_drive.mount 
[Unit]
Description=Mount external drive

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/F474B7AA74B76DCC
Where=/mnt/external_drive
Type=ntfs
Options=rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,nofail

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[chris@archpc ~]$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/mnt-external_drive.automount 
[Unit]
Description=External drive automount
ConditionPathExists=/mnt/external_drive

[Automount]
Where=/mnt/external_drive
TimeoutIdleSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is about all I can find as far as an error message that pointed me to this:

```
Mar 09 11:51:20 archpc systemd[1]: mnt-external_drive.automount: Got automount request for /mnt/external_drive, triggered by 124245 (evince)
```

Am I missing an option or something that has caused these programs to require the mountpoint? I've read through the options and I can't quite grasp why this automount would trigger from either of these programs (I'm sure others would cause it as well, I just started noticing the issue after adding the automount recently).

Comment: I have [the same issue with a NFS automount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692158/problems-with-nfs-systemd-automount). Except for adding a very short Timeout, I haven't found a working solution. Ideally would be if there were an option which checks for the drives existence before attempting to mount.